# iTunes Store Error Message on Ad Hoc Build

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We are testing our iOS app before submitting to the App Store.

The build was compiled with the production certificate and provision was ad hoc.

When we try to do an In-App Purchase we receive error code=0  "Error, Cannot connect to iTunes Store”

What does this mean?

How can we resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: If everything is set up for production (App Store version) then you shouldn't be able to do anything in theory. The reason you will be getting "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" will be because the production version will want the real thing from the store and if your app isn't in the store it will not work. If you're testing go back to your Dev version or Testing version (Depends how you have done it) Otherwise just submit to app store review process, if anything is wrong apple will find it and tell you.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same error today. So probably Apple is doing something to their servers

Answer (score 0):

If you have some Apple ID logged in in AppStore settings, log out (Settings -> iTunes & App Store). After this, when you try IAP in your app, it will ask you for Apple ID, where you can provide ID of your test user to test IAPs.